# Interface Builder issue (Build and go in xCode)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface, interface-builder, objective-c-2.0

I really don't understand this. I downloaded the recent version of xCode 3.2.5 and Interface Builder 3.2.5. I follow these steps:

Create: Window Based Application (iPhone)
Double Click: MainWindow.xib
-- Launches Interface Builder --
selects -> File -> Build and Go in XCode

I get the following error in Interface Builder:

"Interface Builder could not build and go in Xcode.
Build failed (1 error)"

But there are no build errors in Xcode. I don't quite understand what is happening since I am new to this platform. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to Build and Run from Interface Builder. Just switch back (cmd-tab) to XCode and hit cmd-R to Build and Run from there.

Interface Builder is trying to run the xib itself instead of running your Application.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I learned after fiddling around with it. I am going through some tutorials and this error threw me off a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any code?

The best place to start is with one of the getting [started documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Getting+Started#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started).  If you are a registered developer, there are also [videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/iphone/) available in the developer center.

Answer (score -1):

Just save and Build and Go in Xcode. I have a feeling it's because it's a UIWindow rather than a UIViewController. Why did you choose a window-based project?

Comment: Down-voting someone without giving a reason is unproductive. Running a UIWindow from Interface Builder isn't the normal procedure, especially for a beginner so I offered the normal procedure. I also asked why a window-based project was used because the style of the question led me to think the asker is a beginner.

Comment: (I'm not the one who voted you down, fyi). Using a window-based project doesn't seem like a beginner to me. All of the beginning books tell you to use the specific templates and not the window. Once I really understood what I was doing I started using Window-based projects. I consider that to be _generally_ an advanced thing. (He's obviously a beginner though, just saying that the window-based assumption is a little weird to me).

Comment: @Kenny Wyland That makes sense - well said. I looking at it from the perspective that I knew based on their question they weren't an expert so choosing to go Window-based was just selecting a template that sounded the most basic. It definitely detracted from my point though since the accepted answer was otherwise essentially same as mine.